# How to delete local Hg repository

Tags: mercurial, repository, tortoisehg

it's a simple question but i didn't found answers elsewhere.
I need to delete a local Hg repository and all related files without deleting the code, is there a proper command? i thought that deleting the .hg folder wasn't enough.
thanks

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Removing the .hg folder is sufficient. You will lose the VCS metadata (project history, previous versions of all files), which is stored there.

Comment: Also note that there might be some ".hg*" files in your working folder as well that you don't strictly need if you're no longer going to track the files with Mercurial. `.hgsub`, `.hgsubstate` and `.hgignore` are the ones that comes to mind.

Comment: Thanks, my doubt was also about other folders like those